# Голосование бот в Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Можно ли через модуль `PyTelegramBotAPI` сделать голосование типу:

[image: т.е просто обычное голосование]

и если можно то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используйте метод send_poll

пример анонимного вопроса с тремя вариантами ответа:

`bot.send_poll(message.chat.id, 'вопрос', options=['1', '2', '3'])`

[подробнее тут](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/046276b491f3d963d088f85a2bd36f72347b7371/telebot/__init__.py#L1258)